# How to capture every element on sharepoint page on mouse click using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

When I Mouse-click on any element of a SharePoint page, I must be able capture it and be able to add this element's name to a SharePoint list using JavaScript. I have no idea how to do this. Can someone please kindly guide me how this can be achieved? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce javascript list that contains elements you have clicked on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var list = [];
$(document).on('click','*',function () {
        list.push(this);
});});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi LIUFA..Thank you so much for your quick response..! I am new to javascript and I do not know where to put this code. should I put it in the ascx (or) ascx.cs file. Also I did not understand how to check if my sharepoint list is being added with these fetched values? I am sorry for being blunt...can you guide me please!

Comment: @Bhargav You want to put this code into, .ascx file, I have edited my response to copypastable script. I am not sure how do you want to transfer javascript list values to sharepoint list. This mechanism only captures the element that you have clicked on and puts it into javascript list.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation.. Now,I clearly understood this. How can I show the list[0] element in a label. can I put something like the following:                                                          <p id= "Demo"></p>                                                     document.getElementByID("Demo").innerHTML = list[0];

Comment: list[0] contains pointer to element, what you want is value of that element so most likely you are looking for this. <p id= "Demo"></p> $("#Demo").val(list[0].val());